# jQuery countdown every X minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Community,

I wonder how it is possible to create a timer who are restarting every e.g 30 minutes.

I just created this, but that will restart every time I reload the page :c

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ServerTime = new Date( );
    var iTimeStamp = 1412069179 -Math.round( +new Date() / 1000 );
    tTimer( iTimeStamp, "1412076600", "ctfTimer" );
    window.setInterval( 'tTimer(iTimeStamp,"1412076600","ctfTimer")', 250 );
</script>

function tTimer(iEndTimeStamp, iTimeStamp, sElement) {
iTimeStamp = iTimeStamp - Math.round(+new Date() / 1000) - iEndTimeStamp;
oElement = jQuery('#'+sElement);
if (iTimeStamp < 0) {
    oElement.html('00:00:00');
    return false;
}
diffDay = iTimeStamp / (3600 * 24 );
diffDay = diffDay.toString();
diffDay = diffDay.split(".");
diffHour = iTimeStamp / 3600 % 24;
diffHour = diffHour.toString();
diffHour = diffHour.split(".");
diffMin = iTimeStamp / 60 % 60;
diffMin = diffMin.toString();
diffMin = diffMin.split(".");
diffSek = iTimeStamp % 60;
diffSek = diffSek.toString();
diffSek = diffSek.split(".");
if(diffDay[0] != 0){
    oElement.html(diffDay[0] + 'd ' + checkLength(diffHour[0]) + ':' + checkLength(diffMin[0]) + ':' + checkLength(diffSek[0]));
    return true;
}
oElement.text(checkLength(diffHour[0]) + ':' + checkLength(diffMin[0]) + ':' + checkLength(diffSek[0]));
return true;}

function checkLength(sString) {
    sString = sString.toString();
    if (sString.length == 1) {
        sString = '0' + sString;
    }
    return sString;
}
```

I hope you have any hints or tipps for me.
Regards

Comment: You could do this easily with `localStorage`, but based on the name `ctfTimer` I suspect this is for some kind of Capture The Flag contest, is that right? The first thing a contestant will do is hack your timer code to get extra time. You will need to do something server-side if you hope to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael, yeah its for a capture the flag contest, but its just a timer to show when the next ctf is on the server. So I dont need to secure it for hacking.

Comment: Cool, in that case I posted an example of how you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with `localStorage`. Here's an example.

HTML:

```
<div>Time remaining: <span id="timer"></span></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var interval = 30000;

function reset() {
    localStorage.endTime = +new Date + interval;
}

if( ! localStorage.endTime ) {
    reset();
}

setInterval( function() {
    var remaining = localStorage.endTime - new Date;
    if( remaining >= 0 ) {
        $('#timer').text( Math.floor( remaining / 1000 ) );
    } else {
        reset();
    }
}, 100 );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/oL8e6fk9/)

Click Run after the timer starts, or reload the entire fiddle page, to see the timer continue from where it left off.

BTW, when you use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, it is better to pass it an actual function instead of a string with the source code for a function. This is often done with an inline function expression, or you can use a named function.

Since you have duplicate code to call `tTimer()` both immediately and from the timer, that also lets you remove the duplication. Instead of this:

```
tTimer( iTimeStamp, "1412076600", "ctfTimer" );
window.setInterval( 'tTimer(iTimeStamp,"1412076600","ctfTimer")', 250 );
```

You can write this:

```
function tick() {
    tTimer( iTimeStamp, '1412076600', 'ctfTimer' );
}

tick();
setInterval( tick, 250 );
```